# jdbc connection mysql8.0 data format problem

Tags: jdbc, mysql-8.0

100 becomes 100.0 when I connect to mysql8 via JDBC for float data, but 100 when I use navicat or mysql command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty9kC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpf65.png)

Comment: In terms of floating point values, 100 and 100.0 are the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of f variable from float to int
and
use
`f = rs.getInt("f");`
It will work